# Why is my upgrade fetching speed so slow?

Tags: upgrade

This makes me curious...so I'm in the process of upgrading to ubuntu 15.10 [from 15.04], and while it's "getting new packages" it's fetching the files at no more than 58 kb/s....no, im not using dial-up, im using a satellite internet connection, which can be pretty bad but this speed is rediculously slow. It's not taking any time to speak of at all to download youtube videos.

Is there something wrong with the servers im downloading from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently downloading the same update, and it's downloading slightly over 100kb/s while my actual down speed is about six times that right now.

I'm assuming that as the update just started popping up on everyone's desktop today that lots of people are downloading it right now and so the servers are a little overtaxed.

There's nothing "wrong" with the servers, it's just that they only have so much capacity.

Answer (score 0):

15.10 was just released recently, as you know. There's quite a bit of data to be downloaded by quite a few different people. Ubuntu actually has a rather large install base across its many official flavors and all the various derivatives that also rely on the same servers.

People have  been seeding since release, if you have the desire to download the .ISO format and to also alleviate the pressure on the servers then you could consider seeding as well.

A number of people have mentioned seeding in the chat. A not-so-accurate measurement would be my statistics which indicate that Ubuntu is the most sought download, followed by Kubuntu. If you do decide to seed, which is surely appreciated, then those are the two most downloaded files from what I'm able to see. Again, this is hardly a great metric but may help you to decide if you want to help unload some of the traffic from the official servers as I'm sure others are using the bandwidth to download .ISOs instead of just using the upgrade path.

Comment: I feel like only the first paragraph of this has really anything to do with the question. The rest feels like self-promotion in order to increase your seed ratio...

Comment: I'll edit it to make you happy but that wasn't my intent - the intent was to encourage other to share and to use torrents to ease the pressure on the server. I'll think of how to reword it for you - thanks for pointing it out.